# how can i populate an axios get data array and pass it to a Vuejs component props to do list rendering in the component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Given I have a component called upload-csv

```
Vue.component('upload-csv',{
 props:['clientnames'],
 template:`
    <ul>
       <li v-for="clientname in clientnames">{{ clientname.name }}</li>
    </ul>
 `
});
```

Then a Vue Instance

```
new Vue({
 el:"#upload-csv-component",
 data:{
  loadurl:'http://localhost/startup/public/index.php/loadnames',
  clientnames:[]
 },
 mounted:function(){
  axios.get(this.loadurl)
  .then(function(response){
   this.clientnames = response.data;
  })
  .catch(function(error){});
 }
});
```

Wish to use it this way

```
<div id="upload-csv-component">
  <upload-csv :clientnames="clientnames"></upload-csv>
</div>
```

But the list is not rendering; I have changed mounted hook to beforeMount yet the list is not rendering.

Please can someone suggest a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an arrow function to keep access to `this` inside the axios request:

```js
mounted(){
  axios.get(this.loadurl)
  .then((response) => {
    this.clientnames = response.data
  })
}
```

(great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/9541423) about `this` context)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that axios requires the fat arrow syntax, as shown here
[Using Axios to Consume APIs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)

```js
console.clear();

Vue.component('upload-csv',{
 props:['clientnames'],
 template:`
    <ul>
       <li v-for="clientname in clientnames">{{ clientname.name }}</li>
    </ul>
 `
});

new Vue({
 el:"#upload-csv-component",
 data () {
   return {       
     loadurl:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
     clientnames:[]
   }
 },
 mounted:function(){
  axios.get(this.loadurl)
  .then(response => {
   console.log(response);
   this.clientnames = response.data;
  })
  .catch(function(error){});
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="upload-csv-component">
  <h1>Clients</h1>
  <upload-csv :clientnames="clientnames"></upload-csv>
</div>
```